# Rails3 routing: how to direct two requests to a single entry point

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my controller I would like to use the same code for the new and edit requests. Like this:

```
def edit
  @tag= Tag.find(params[:id]) || Tag.new
end
```

My question is: how do I indicate this in routes.rb (Rails3)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you are using resources routes just like this one:

```
# routes.rb
resources :tags
```

This will create new and create for you.

Suppose you only want new maps to edit, but remaining create unchanged, use the following:

```
get "/tags/new" => "tags#edit", :as => :new_tag_path
resources :tags
```

The order is important. The upper one will be matched first. And so if the path is `/tags/new`, it will be routed to edit action. And because it is matched already, it won't go down and so although `resources :tags` defines also the `/tags/new` to new action, no routing will be successfully matched.

So adding the only one line is ok.